# Lwuit app in Blackberry Torch

Tags: java, java-me, porting, lwuit, blackberry-torch

These days Im doing the same thing, which is building my blackberry applications for Blackberry Torch. But I couldn't do that coz it gives an exception.It is not working. But the other forums said that get the newest source and create a Blackberry port jar and I did that but Im still getting that error.

Comment: And if what @bhakki said still doesn't work, try posting the actual error message...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with my application. I was using LWUIT 1.4 as released on August 2010.

I first downloaded the latest LWUIT sources from SVN but the same exception occured again.

I solved my problem finally, to make it work on the Torch, I had to compile the project with BB JDE 6.0.

Yannik Soubigou